# File Input/Output: Countries

Tags: java, file, input, output

I am working on a exercise which requires the program to read a text file of a specific format, which stores each line in an ArrayList (Using Generics).

Below is the text file which contains the capital cities, their population and the country in which they are:

```
London 7500000 UK
Rome 2700000 Italy
Paris 6000000 France
Berlin 4500000 Germany
Athens 3800000 Greece
Budapest 1700000 Hungary 
Lisbon 2800000 Portugal
Madrid 5600000 Spain
Oslo 1300000 Norway 
Copenhagen 1200000 Denmark
```

This is the code:

```
class Countries
{
    public static void main(String[] param)
    {
        Vector v = new Vector();
        int input = Integer.parseInt(param[0]);
        try
        {
            FileReader file = new FileReader("data.txt");
            BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(file);
            for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
            {
                String read = buffer.readLine();
                v.addElement(read);              
                System.out.println(v.elementAt(i));
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }        
        getPopulation(v,input);      
    }

    public static void getPopulation(Vector v, int input)
    {
        Vector v1 = new Vector();        
       for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
       {
            String str = (String) v.elementAt(i);
            int num = str.indexOf(" ");
            int num2 = str.lastIndexOf(" ");
            String pop = str.substring(num+1,num2);
            pop.trim();
            v1.addElement(pop);
            System.out.println(v1.elementAt(i));
       }
       check(v1,input);
    }

    public static void check(Vector v1, int input)
    {
      int count = 0;
      for(int i=0; i <10; i++)
      {

          try 
          {
            String s = (String) v1.elementAt(i);
            int test = Integer.parseInt(s.trim());

            if (input >= test)
            {
            count++;
            }
          }
        catch (NumberFormatException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }

      }

        System.out.println(count + " countries are greater than or equal to " + input);

    }
}
```

The program should read each line and be able to answer how many capitals have a populations of equal to, or larger than the command-line argument.

Now the **problem** is when running the command-line argument for example {"5000000"} it should give 3. However it gives 4 (which is wrong).

It would be appreciated if anyone could help me spot on where I am going wrong.

Comment: You realize your condition `if (input >= test)` gives you cities which have *less* people than `input`, do you?

Comment: You're solving the problem in the wrong way. Instead of storing Strings in your list, and being forced to parse them every time you want an information (city, population, etc.), you should parse the lines as you read them, transform them into instances of a class Country, and thus store the countries in a List<Country>. You could then iterate through the list and simply call country.getPopulation() to have the population as an integer. Also, forget about Vector. It shouldn't be used anymore since Java 2. We're at Java 8. Use ArrayList.